# How to get Optional class with jersey client

Tags: java, java-8, option-type, jersey-client

I'm trying getting the optional class with jersey client. When the remote server returns `Optional.empty()`, I'm getting this error.

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "present" (class java.util.Optional), not marked as ignorable
```

My code

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.registerModule(new Jdk8Module());

Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient().register(new JacksonJsonProvider(mapper));
Optional<MyType> myType = client.target(TARGET_URL)
                    .path(PATH)
                    .request()
                    .get(Optional.class);
```

My related dependencies are as

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jdk8</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.1</version>
</dependency>
```

EDIT

The application that running on the remote server is a spring boot app. I added **jackson-datatype-jdk8** dependency on the app. After this, the **Unrecognized field exception** solved but the return object is null. Before this, the postman was returned the following result

```
{
    "present": false
}
```

But now

```
null
```

Comment: this? https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8

Comment: @Eugene Unfortunately, it did not work

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the [`@JsonInclude(Include.NON_EMPTY)`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonInclude.Include.html#NON_EMPTY) to annotate such a filed.

> Value that indicates that only properties that have values that values
>   *that are null or what is considered empty are not* to be included.

Comment: I added this annotation in my class top level both client and away  but I get still the error